# How to create "recommended content" widget in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, widget

i saw a "recommended content" widget in webs and i want to create one to my website.
Example of widget i found online: [widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1wcU.png)

i want to create a widget in HTML&CSS similar to the photo i added. widget with 3 pictures side by side and below each picture a linked text to another web.

would  i like to know what is the best way to approch it ?
do it with cols and rows ? maybe cards will be better ? or is it another way ?

Comment: Please don't ask opinion based questions. You try the approach first if you are stuck somewhere in the code then you ask question here with the code.

Comment: that depends on YOU, if you're good at designing cards, do it, if you are good at cols and rows, do it, and it depends on what you want to do so if the user can hide a one, cards can solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

is this what you want.

```css
h1{
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
a {
  font-family: Roboto;
 }
.blog-card-blog {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.blog-card {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.blog-card .blog-card-image {
    height: 60%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 38px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56), 0 4px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.blog-card .blog-card-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.blog-card .blog-table {
    padding: 15px 30px;
}
.blog-table {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.blog-category {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
.blog-text-success {
    color: #28a745!important;
}
.blog-card-blog .blog-card-caption {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.blog-card-caption {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", "Times New Roman", serif;
}
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.blog-card-caption, .blog-card-caption a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

p {
    color: #3C4857;
}

p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.blog-card .ftr {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.blog-card .ftr .author {
    color: #888;
}

.blog-card .ftr div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.blog-card .author .avatar {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;blog-
}
.blog-card .ftr .stats {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.blog-card .ftr .stats {
    float: right;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="blog-card blog-card-blog">
    <div class="blog-card-image">
        <a href="#"> <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1084/535/353?grayscale"> </a>
        <div class="ripple-cont"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-table">
        <h6 class="blog-category blog-text-success"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i> News</h6>
        <h4 class="blog-card-caption">
            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and</a>
        </h4>
        <p class="blog-card-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        <div class="ftr">
            <div class="author">
                <a href="#"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/5760/3840" alt="..." class="avatar img-raised"> <span>Lorem</span> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="stats"> <i class="far fa-clock"></i> 10 min </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="blog-card blog-card-blog">
    <div class="blog-card-image">
        <a href="#"> <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1084/536/354?grayscale"> </a>
        <div class="ripple-cont"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-table">
        <h6 class="blog-category blog-text-success"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i> News</h6>
        <h4 class="blog-card-caption">
            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and</a>
        </h4>
        <p class="blog-card-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        <div class="ftr">
            <div class="author">
                <a href="#"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/5760/3840" alt="..." class="avatar img-raised"> <span>Lorem</span> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="stats"> <i class="far fa-clock"></i> 10 min </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="blog-card blog-card-blog">
    <div class="blog-card-image">
        <a href="#"> <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1084/536/354?grayscale"> </a>
        <div class="ripple-cont"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-table">
        <h6 class="blog-category blog-text-success"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i> News</h6>
        <h4 class="blog-card-caption">
            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and</a>
        </h4>
        <p class="blog-card-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        <div class="ftr">
            <div class="author">
                <a href="#"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/5760/3840" alt="..." class="avatar img-raised"> <span>Lorem</span> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="stats"> <i class="far fa-clock"></i> 10 min </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Credit: www.bootdey.com/snippets/view/Responsive-UI-Card -->
```

Comment: "Is this what you want?" is not an answer but another question. 200 lines of code without any description is likely to raise more questions. And ... Why do you post this twice?

Comment: thanks, but i try to do it without bootstrap. thats why i ask about the best way